# HL7 FHIR - How to modify the FHIR Schema and Run in local server

Tags: hapi-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure, hl7-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I'm trying to extend and override the FHIR schema and run it on the local server.
Could you please suggest me is there any way to customize the FHIR schema and run in local

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if you want to just download the FHIR schemas, you're free to edit them to your heart's content and, but if your instances aren't valid against the un-edited schemas, then your systems will not be FHIR-conformant and you won't interoperate with systems or tools that depend on FHIR conformance (which is most of them).

Also, be aware that the schemas only reflect a small portion of the rules for conformance.  XML schemas don't check slicing, vocabulary bindings, invariants or logs of other rules that must also be met.  Most systems using FHIR don't use schema validation at all, or use it only as an initial "quick check" and will still conduct more thorough code-based validation against he rules in the FHIR spec.

There should never be a situation where you *need* to modify the FHIR schemas.  The expectation in FHIR is that the 'extension' element will be used to convey additional data elements if any are required.  If you need to represent a concept that FHIR doesn't have a resource for at all, then you can use 'basic'.  In some cases (if the element doesn't have a required vocabulary binding) you may be able to send an extension such as 'data-absent-reason' in place of sending an actual value.   The only situation where there's no mechanism to avoid populating an element and sending it as FHIR requires is if there's a mandatory coded element with a required binding.  Those are both rare and generally easy to satisfy, though you may need to map your internal codes to FHIR to populate the element.

Rather than trying to modify the schema, you might be better served by asking the community (e.g. http://chat.fhir.org) how to meet your needs within the FHIR specification as it stands.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I'm new to FHIR, I'm just curious to know about is it possible to create my own FHIR service Instance by overriding the schema and cardinality values? for example - If the resource "patient" I want to change the cardinality value of the "active" property and run it in my local server with these changes. Is it possible? Could you please suggest to me